# How to read a veracrypt encrypted drive on a Ubuntu VM?

Tags: usb, mount, virtualbox, veracrypt

I've installed VirtualBox 6.1.12 on a new desktop and installed Ubuntu 20.04 and have it up and running. I installed the VM extension packs, guest additions, appropriate groups (vboxsf, vboxusers) and I'm able to access other USB keys when I plug them in.

I have files from my old machine on a Veracrypt encrypted 500 GB USB drive which I would like to be able to access. On my old Linux box running an earlier version of Ubuntu I had to mount the drive with the Veracrypt GUI when I plugged it in. I'm unable to access the drive in the VM when it's selected and it's not recognized when running the Veracrypt GUI.

Is this a limitation of using Ubuntu on a VM with an encrypted drive, or am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured it out. When mounting the drive Veracrypt needed the admin password from the machine it was originally created on, not the admin password of the machine I was trying to mount it on.